# msbuild under cygwin mintty stops working

Tags: msbuild, cygwin

I've been running msbuild.exe from my mintty shell for several weeks.  Suddenly (well, after a bit of messing with things like terminal type and colors, etc) msbuild hangs the shell.  If I do something simple like $ msbuild -?  it just hangs.  No screen output, no nothing.  I have to physically close the shell to get beyond it.

I've checked other shell apps (e.g. csc.exe) and they all still work fine.  Not at all sure what could've happened.  I've even gone so far as to re-install cygwin to another drive, but still no joy.

any logs or ideas?  getting desperate here....

Comment: So, bit more info... seems this is limited to mintty, and this machine.  Tried the cmd version of the shell and msbuild working fine there.  Also fine in every other variant I have installed (powershell, gitbash, etc).  I'll go looking for ways to log activity from mintty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Having same problem with fresh cygwin install on win7 PC.

Seems problem with latest versions of cygwin:
http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2012-03/msg00215.html

Upgrade to latest snapshot fix the problem:
http://cygwin.com/snapshots/

Unpack cygwin1-20120517.dll.bz2 and replace bin/cygwin1.dll

Cheers.